# Partial matches with postgresql full-text search using texticle on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, texticle

Trying to get searching working on Heroku using partial search

The following query generates an SQL error on Heroku, but works correctly in my locally version:

```
@events.search(params[:search]+":*")
```

I am using the Heroku shared database service, is this a possible difference in syntax between PostgreSQL versions?

What syntax should I be using to do a partial matching searching against a full-text index in PostgreSQL 8?

Comment: Of course there are differences between versions. You already suspect version differences. Would seem prudent to mention your version. Heroku shared should be 8.3. You may be interested: [Heroku offers PostgreSQL 9.1](https://postgres.heroku.com/blog/past/2012/1/18/postgresql_91_available_in_beta/) in beta by now.

Comment: Yes, but what are the differences? The docs don't suggest there is a different syntax between 8 and 9.

Comment: You can use `%` for partial matches. Have you tried it? i.e,  `@events.search("#{params[:search]}:%")`

Comment: The % syntax works with LIKE, but does not appear to be supported within PG's full-text search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that PostgreSQL version 8 does not support partial searches using the :* syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the [changes in PostgreSQL 9.1](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.1).

Perhaps you could try using string interpolation instead of concatenation.

```
@events.search("#{params[:search]}:*")
```

I'm not really sure what the kiss emoticon :* adds to [texticle](https://github.com/tenderlove/texticle)'s functionality. Maybe I need to learn more SQL.

Comment: That is the same syntax that is failing on PostgreSQL Version 8. I have tried both concatenation and interpolation. The syntax is meant to be for partial matches, similar to an SQL "LIKE 'search%'".

Comment: This is something that I'd like to do with texticle as well. I can't find anything in the texticle docs about partial searches. You can however accomplish this with the pg_search gem, using the :prefix => true option. That's probably not what you want to hear though.

Comment: I found a commit on github that hints at what you're trying to do. https://github.com/tenderlove/texticle/commit/aff41d690b5dcb595bfa0ed8f21509859c4e6519

Answer (score 1):

As http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-PARSING-QUERIES says, using ":*" is for specify prefix matching. E.g. If searching "Australia" with "Aus:*" will work but not "ust:*".

So concat OR xxxx LIKE "%yyy%" will works better

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tsearch option with a prefix:

```
:tsearch => {:prefix => true}
```